# Pandas - Error: Can only compare identically-labeled series objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I can't figure out the reason of an error I get on a code I've run so many times before.

To give you some content, I'm working with a data frame that looks like this:

| User_ID | Name | Boss |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | John |
| 2 | Laura | Maria |
| 3 | Claire | John |

I need to create a new column, Boss_ID, that shows the Boss_ID taken from another dataframe. The second dataframe, indeed, looks like this:

| ID | Boss_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 54 |
| 2 | 78 |
| 3 | 54 |

Normally, I would run the following code:

`df['Boss_ID'] = np.where(df['User_ID']==df_1['ID'],df_1['Boss_ID'],df[Boss_ID'])`

I've tried everything, renaming the columns for User_ID so that they have the same name, reset indexes, checked whether each column was of the same tyoe...

Yet, I always get the message: **Can only compare identically-labeled series objects**

I ended up using merge but I'd like to get to the root of the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Focus on `df['User_ID']==df_1['ID']`.  What's indices of the two series?

Comment: If this ran before, but not now, it's likely that the row indices don't match in the current case.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example that produces your error

```
In [72]: df=pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3],index=[4,6,8],columns=['ID'])
In [73]: df
Out[73]: 
   ID
4   1
6   2
8   3
In [74]: df1=pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3],index=[4,6,8],columns=['ID1'])
```

difference in column name doesn't matter:

```
In [75]: df1['ID1']==df['ID']
Out[75]: 
4    True
6    True
8    True
dtype: bool
```

Difference in index does:

```
In [76]: df2=pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3],index=[4,6,9],columns=['ID1'])
In [77]: df2['ID1']==df['ID']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-77-d3d602ee9ac7>", line 1, in <module>
    df2['ID1']==df['ID']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py", line 65, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py", line 29, in __eq__
    return self._cmp_method(other, operator.eq)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4973, in _cmp_method
    raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

If you pay attention to the traceback, you'll see that this is a `pandas` error, not a `numpy` one!

Extracting arrays from the Series throws away in the `index`, and allows comparison by position only:

```
In [78]: df2['ID1'].to_numpy()==df['ID'].to_numpy()
Out[78]: array([ True,  True,  True])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback! Shouldn't a reset index action fix the problem and then allow me to run the code I want to run?

Comment: I don't know.  You've only shown a tabular display of the frames.  I can't recreate or test your frames from that.